# Comparing One Link List to Another Blacklist versus Word Frequency List C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, member-functions, blacklist, word-cloud

I have created a program that will read a text file and put the words as strings into a linked list, along with their frequency count throughout the text file.  It only prints one occurrence of each word with the total times it appeared.

My program also loads a blacklist, in which it is supposed to compare the blacklist linked list to the word cloud (or word frequency) linked list, and then remove the blacklisted words from the word frequency list.

I have tried doing this several ways. The following is my 3rd version.  What I am wanting to do is add a Boolean value to each node, and when one node is equal to a word in the blacklist, the Boolean value will be true. However, I am not getting it to print right with the following code. I have searched, and I can't seem to find the correct syntax to add a Boolean value to a node in linked list.

EDIT #3:

```
void wordCloud::compareWith(wordCloud& wordList, wordCloud& badList){
wordNode *wordListTemp, *blacklistTemp, *temp = NULL;
unsigned int counter = 0;

for (blacklistTemp = badList.head; blacklistTemp; blacklistTemp = blacklistTemp->next){
    cout << blacklistTemp->myWord << "\n";
    for (wordListTemp = wordList.head; wordListTemp; wordListTemp = wordListTemp->next){

        if (wordListTemp->myWord != blacklistTemp->myWord){

            wordListTemp->blacklist = false;
            if (wordListTemp->blacklist = false){
                cout << wordListTemp->myWord << " <"
                    << wordListTemp->freq_count << ">\n";
            }
        }
        else if (wordListTemp->myWord == blacklistTemp->myWord){
            cout << blacklistTemp->myWord << " " << wordListTemp->myWord << "\n";
            wordListTemp->blacklist = true;
            if (wordListTemp->blacklist = true)
                cout << wordListTemp->myWord << "\n";
        } 
    }
    //counter++;
    cout << blacklistTemp->myWord << " " << wordListTemp->myWord << "\n";
}

system("pause");
}
```

This is not complete, but it is as far as I have gotten. The problem is it only prints the true if, and will not print any false if. Even if I switch the values, it will still only print the true if's. So I am assuming that I am going about this wrong. What would be the correct way to "flag" a node true and "flag" a node false? All the cout's are for debugging purposes.  I will remove or comment those out later.

Comment: It's a naive implementation, but why not just do two while loops, one within the other? You go over the blacklist on the external one, and in the internal, you compare your current blacklist word to all the words of your wordList? It can obviously be optimized, but at least it'll give you a working start.

Comment: @o_weisman Yeah, maybe I am looking into this too much. That is actually what I am trying to do now. I am a little slow on the problem solving porting of coding, so I will post back if there is any success.

Comment: @o_weisman - I did attemp this, but didn't seem to get anywhere. I posted the code above, but the program still freezes.

Comment: @CharllWillia6 The following line is wrong: if (blacklistTemp == wordListTemp)  You're comparing two memory locations to each other, and they are obviously not the same memory location (if they were that would be even worse). You need to compare wordListTemp->myWord to blackListTemp->myWord. OH, and it freezes, because you need to put the line wordListTemp = wordListTemp->next; outside of the if block.

Comment: I think you need to learn how to debug your code anyway. If it's so obvious I can see the errors without debugging, it shouldn't be asked on the forum honestly.

Comment: @o_weisman Yes you are correct, I probably need to learn better debug techniques, and I only know how to run the Visual Studio debugger, and step-in, and when it still freezes on a step-in, I don't really know what to do. So yes, if you could direct me to a good source of tutorials or information on debugging, that would be great. But my code is on this forum because I need assistance getting it to work. I did what you said. Makes sensee what you said. Thank you. But it still doesn't work. So that is why my question is on the forum.

Comment: If you updated your code according to what I said, you should maybe update your question, but I'm relatively sure that those are two errors that cause freezing. If you're stuck on a particular line, then you should tell us what it is so we can help you better.

Comment: Updated the question. No, the program does not freeze anymore.  But the function does nothing. No, there is no particular line. Just need assistance solving this problem. I don't understand why `wordListTemp = wordListTemp->next;` goes outside the if statement. I see that it does not freeze. But at the same time, I am deleting temp and not setting wordListTemp on to the next node into the list. I feel that I need to set wordListTemp to a new node, before I try deleting the node it was first pointing to. So I don't understand this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!!

With a lot of old fashion debugging and cout statements, I finally got what I wanted. I know this might have been easy for some, but with not being very familiar with linked lists, this was quite the process for me.

Before I was trying to delete words that were seen in the blacklist linked list out of the `wordList` linked list.  I decided later to just try to add a boolean value of true to the nodes in `wordList`, and then adjust my print function to not print nodes with the value of true. I also had to tweak a few things in `insertWord()`, and my `freqSort()` functions, but all that really consisted of was adding a pointer to the boolean value when a new node was being created.

My member function is `void wordCloud::compareWith(wordCloud& wordList, wordCloud& badList)`, and is part of my wordCloud class. Here is the following definition:

```
void wordCloud::compareWith(const wordCloud& wordList, const wordCloud& badList){
wordNode *wordListTemp, *blacklistTemp;
unsigned int counter = 0;

//loop that advances wordListTemp
for (wordListTemp = wordList.head; wordListTemp; wordListTemp = wordListTemp->next){
    blacklistTemp = badList.head;

    //loop advances blacklistTemp - compares links in wordList to badList(blacklist)
    //and sets the node to true if myWord equals any word in the blacklist
    while (blacklistTemp){          
        if (wordListTemp->myWord == blacklistTemp->myWord){
            wordListTemp->blacklist = true; 
            counter++;
        }
        blacklistTemp = blacklistTemp->next;
    }

    //for debugging
    //cout << blacklistTemp->myWord << " " << wordListTemp->myWord << "\n";     
}

/*********************  All for debugging  ***************************************
cout << "True:\n\n";
wordListTemp = wordList.head;       //reset wordListTemp to head    

while (wordListTemp){               //print blacklisted words from wordList
    if (wordListTemp->blacklist == true){
        cout << wordListTemp->myWord << " <"
            << wordListTemp->freq_count << ">\n";
    }
    wordListTemp = wordListTemp->next;
}
//prints total words blacklisted
cout << "There are " << counter << " blacklisted words.";                   

cout << "\n\nFalse:\n\n";
wordListTemp = wordList.head;       //reset wordListTemp to head    
counter = 0;

while (wordListTemp){               //print non-blacklisted words from wordList
    if (wordListTemp->blacklist == false){
        cout << wordListTemp->myWord << " <"
            << wordListTemp->freq_count << ">\n";
        counter++;
    }
    wordListTemp = wordListTemp->next;
}
//prints total words not blacklisted
cout << "There are " << counter << " words that are not blacklisted.\n";

system("pause");    
********************  End debugging *******************************************/    
}
```

So basically this is a comparison function that flags nodes that are found in another list. Works well and tested with all other options.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could always debug step-by-step to see just which portion of the code freezes up your comp. The better way to detect memory leaks would be to use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

On a side note, I would implement that comparison function as a comparison operator, and implement a comparison operator for their Nodes as well (for convenience). Doing so divides the code a bit and helps, later on, understand where your problem is. It is also a better way to do it (more readable, OOP-y, etc).

Comment: Not exactly sure how to do that or understand exactly what you are saying.

Comment: Which part did you not understand? The Valgrind or the operators?

Comment: The operators and implementing as a comparison operator. I know what comparison operators are, but just not how to "implement" the solution as a comparison operator. Are you talking about overloading?